# Calling JAX-WS web service form another JAX-WS webserice

Tags: java, web-services

I have one Logging web service in my project which gets called form another web service.

I am calling a logging web service using a wrapper method which points to the web service method.
When I am  accessing it using client-webservice structure I am not getting any exception.

But the problem is when I am accessing it form web service-to-web service call using Wrapper structure. It cribs gives an exception:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: webservices.ActivityLoggerWS is
>   not an interface

Here is the problematic code:

```
 webservices.ActivityLoggerWSService service = new 
 webservices.ActivityLoggerWSService();
 webservices.ActivityLoggerWS port = service.getActivityLoggerWSPort();//this line throws Exception
 port.logEvent(activityLogStruct);
```

I am clueless where things are getting wrong.

Comment: Have you opened the ActivityLoggerWS.java and see if its an interface or not? As per the default naming conventions of the generated java code it should be an interface.

Comment: Yes Bhushan,It is an Interface.

Comment: i got resolved the problem.But i still dont know what was the problem,Because i tried after some time and it worked,but this time i created the new stubs.May the problem was with the IDE(NeatBeans 6.5),but i am not sure with that also.